# Validate "Any" with validateValue: forKey in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, kvc

I'm writing to CoreData with key-values:

```
entity.setValue(value: <Any?>, forKey: <String>)
```

Before writing to CoreData I store the value and the field name in vars:

```
var value: Any?
var field: String
```

I would like to do a simple validation **before** I attempt to write to CoreData. The function validateValue(_:forKey:) seems to satisfy my needs but I don't understand how to use it:

```
try entity.validateValue(_ value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, forKey: String)
```

In my case it would be like:

```
    do {
        try entity.validateValue(value, forKey: field)
    } catch {
        let validationError = error as NSError
        print(validationError)
    }
```

But how do I pass

```
var value: Any
```

to

```
AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>
```

Is it even possible to use the validateValue function in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using setValue(forKey:) instead of accessing the properties of your model class directly? `entity.someValue = 42` instead of `entity.setValue(42, forKey: "someValue")`

Comment: I have a pretty complex input model and the key-value approach would save me a lot of duplicate coding. =)

Comment: And using `Any` instead of the actual type of the value will make it less complex? Anyway, have you looked into overriding validateForInsert/validateForUpdate instead?

Comment: Well, you just have to trust me on that. :) Yes, I have Iooked into validateForInsert/Update too but since I want to validate the inputs individually, validateValue seems like a more suitable choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `let pointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>(&value)`.

You should read the docs of `validateValue` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506776-validatevalue) to ensure you are using it correctly (e.g. implementing `validate<Key>:error:`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this gives me the dreaded "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6e617041)" error. I edited my question with a snippet of error handling. Does it look correct?